# Make <SVG /> dynamically fit the whole screen, depending on screen size in React-Native for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, react-native, svg

I have a svg called `<BackgroundPattern />` and I want to use this svg as my background. Depending on the device the App is running in, the height and width of the screen changes. I want my `<BackgroundPattern />` adjust to this automatically...
How would I do that?

Here is a snack https://snack.expo.dev/TlbzoyrxR

Comment: Load the background as hidden, Calculate the width and height of the viewport. Change the width and height of background. Make it visible

Comment: I'd save the svg as file and include it as CSS background image, then use `background-size: cover`